# uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the error uncaught type error undefined is not a function in the 2nd line of below function whenever i try to run my code.

```
$(function () {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", $("#hdnActiveTabIndex").val());
  HideExtraGridColumns();
});
```

Comment: Sounds like your `tabs` plugin isn't loading properly.

Comment: Would you please let me know what will be the right Plugin tabs.

Comment: You need to load the [jQueryUI library](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).

Comment: I included the jQueryUI library but still facing the problem.Actually i have 3 blocks and 1 tab for each block and wants to show only that tab on which i click and remaining blocks should get hide.let me know how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This means `tabs()` is not a function, so there's something wrong in another part of your code or you didn't load a script correctly.

Comment: Hi Alex i tried to include the jquery UI Plugin but still facing the issue. Can i send you the complete code on mail so that we can get the actual solution